# なぜトランポリンという命名なのでしょうか？

Tags: swift, java, reactive-programming, rx-swift

RxJavaに `Schedulers.trampoline()` というスケジューラがあります。

RxSwiftでは `CurrentThreadScheduler`が同様のようです。

引用：
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Schedulers.md

> Schedules units of work on the current thread. This is the default
>   scheduler for operators that generate elements.
>
> This scheduler is also sometimes called a "trampoline scheduler".

ここにも "trampoline scheduler" と呼ばれることがあると説明でてきています。

**トランポリン**というと飛び跳ねて遊ぶ器具ですよね。
どうしてこのような命名となったのでしょうか？

Comment: RxJava触ったことないので本当に関係あるか分からないのですが、トランポリンというとプログラミング独特の言い回しがあるので関係するかもしれません: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)

Comment: お。コンピュータ特有のいろんな意味があるんですね！

Comment: 参考: 英語版での類似質問と回答 - [Rxjava why Schedulers.trampoline() named 'trampoline'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41297519) / コメントが分かりやすいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[コメントした](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/57801/%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9c%e3%83%88%e3%83%a9%e3%83%b3%e3%83%9d%e3%83%aa%e3%83%b3%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e5%91%bd%e5%90%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b#comment62269_57801) リンク先の内容も踏まえて、日本語的には恐らく **打てば響く** 状態を指したいのだろうと考えると、代わりに「ピンポン(=卓球)」や「壁打ち」でも意味は通じそうですが、ピンポンは1対1だし、壁打ちも1単語でスマートに収まら無さそうなので、トランポリンは言い得て妙なのかなと思います。